# Return function Javascript

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I have several problems with return of queries.

Here, what I would like to do :

```
//If the email hasn't a good format
if(email_not_good_format())
   //I do something
else if(email_already_exists_in_mysql(email))
  //I do something


function email_already_exists_in_mysql(email){
connection.query('SELECT COUNT(*) AS nb FROM user WHERE emailUser = ' + connection.escape(email), function(err, rows, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;
        if(rows[0].nb == 0)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    });
}
```

I saw on different posts callback function but it doesn't work for what I want to do.

Comment: for async work on JS take a look to promises. You have the Q library for node.js.

Comment: The call to `.query` is *asynchronous*. That's why you have to provide a callback. Have a look at this question to understand the problem and for a potential solution: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/218196 (even though it's about Ajax, the same principals apply).

Comment: @TMichel r u getting any error.

Comment: You're attempting to perform a synchronous set of actions using an asynchronous language. You might like to start with some tutorials on JavaScript before attempting something a little more complex like database connections. Have you looked at any JavaScript tutorials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I saw on different posts callback function but it doesn't work for what I want to do.

Yes it does, you just need to change the way you think about code. Instead of writing `email_already_exists_in_mysql` you should instead write a function called `if_email_already_exists_in_mysql`:

```
/* Executes callback if email
 * already exists in mysql:
 */
function if_email_already_exists_in_mysql (email,callback) {
    connection.query(
        'SELECT COUNT(*) AS nb FROM user WHERE emailUser = ' +
        connection.escape(email),

        function(err, rows, fields) {
            if(rows[0].nb != 0) {
                callback();
            }
        }
    )
}
```

Then instead of writing this:

```
//If the email hasn't a good format
if(email_not_good_format()) {
    //I do something
}
else if(email_already_exists_in_mysql(email)) {
    //I do something
}
```

you write it like this instead:

```
//If the email hasn't a good format
if(email_not_good_format()) {
    //I do something
}
else {if_email_already_exists_in_mysql(email),function(){
    //I do something
})}
```

Now, you may ask yourself, what if there is another else after that? Well, you need to modify the `if_email_already_exists_in_mysql` function to behave like and `if...else` instead of just and `if`:

```
function if_email_already_exists_in_mysql (email,callback,else_callback) {
    connection.query(
        'SELECT COUNT(*) AS nb FROM user WHERE emailUser = ' +
        connection.escape(email),

        function(err, rows, fields) {
            if(rows[0].nb != 0) {
                callback();
            }
            else if(else_callback) {
                else_callback();
            }
        }
    )
}
```

so that you can call it like this:

```
//If the email hasn't a good format
if(email_not_good_format()) {
    //I do something
}
else {
    if_email_already_exists_in_mysql(email),function(){
        //I do something
    },
    // else
    function(){
        //I do something else
    }
)}
```

You can write async code to do pretty much anything regular code can do only instead of returning a value you pass in a callback. Remember:

**return** in synchronous code == passing in **callbacks** in asynchronous code.

The code structure must therefore be different but as I demonstrated above the logic you want to implement can be exactly the same.